# Jetpack compose Custom Shadow using drawBehind not working as expected in api 26 (oreo)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I was trying to implement a custom shadow modifier in jetpack compose using drawBehind and drawIntoCanvas, This works perfectly fine from api 28 (pie) but the Blur effect is not working as expected in api 26 (oreo) It only draws a rectangle into canvase but the MaskFilter is not working.

Any reason why ?, is BlurMaskFilter not supported ?

I have attached the code snippet of the modifier function and relevant images.

```js
fun Modifier.shadowCustom(
    color: Color = Color.Black,
    offsetX: Dp = 0.dp,
    offsetY: Dp = 0.dp,
    blurRadius: Dp = 0.dp,
    shapeRadius: Dp = 0.dp,
) = composed  {
    val paint: Paint = remember { Paint() }
    val blurRadiusPx = blurRadius.px(LocalDensity.current)
    val maskFilter = remember {
        BlurMaskFilter(blurRadiusPx, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL)
    }
    drawBehind {
        drawIntoCanvas { canvas ->
            val frameworkPaint = paint.asFrameworkPaint()
            if (blurRadius != 0.dp) {
                frameworkPaint.maskFilter = maskFilter
            }
            frameworkPaint.color = color.toArgb()

            val leftPixel = offsetX.toPx()
            val topPixel = offsetY.toPx()
            val rightPixel = size.width + leftPixel
            val bottomPixel = size.height + topPixel

            if (shapeRadius > 0.dp) {
                val radiusPx = shapeRadius.toPx()
                canvas.drawRoundRect(
                    left = leftPixel,
                    top = topPixel,
                    right = rightPixel,
                    bottom = bottomPixel,
                    radiusX = radiusPx,
                    radiusY = radiusPx,
                    paint = paint,
                )
            } else {
                canvas.drawRect(
                    left = leftPixel,
                    top = topPixel,
                    right = rightPixel,
                    bottom = bottomPixel,
                    paint = paint,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun Dp.px(density: Density): Float =
    with(density) { toPx() }
```

[image: Shadow on Api 26 (oreo)]

[image: Shadow on ap]

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `BlurMaskFilter` works with Hardware Acceleration only as of Android API 28 (https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/hardware-accel#drawing-support).

It's either you set your app or activity to stop being hardware accelerated (not sure if this is recommended as this might have performance impacts):

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <activity ... />
    <activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
</application>
```

or you can try to use a gradient approach to emulate the shadow effect instead as follows (The following code is adapted to your case):

```
val bottomGradient = LinearGradientShader(
   from = Offset(x = 0f, y = size.height),
   to = Offset(x = 0f, y = size.height + blurRadius),
   colors = listOf(color, Color.Transparent),
)
canvas.drawRoundRect(
   left = leftPixel,
   top = size.height + topPixel,
   right = rightPixel,
   bottom = bottomPixel + blurRadius,
   radiusX = radiusPx,
   radiusY = radiusPx,
   paint = Paint().apply {
      shader = bottomGradient
   },
)
```

For sure you can edit the `colorStops` and the code to match what you want. It cannot fully replace the blur effect but it can be a replacement especially if you use it only for old devices, and you use the blur for the new ones.

Hope to have helped.